# How to fix partially installed SDK android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I am using Android Studio 2.3 IDE and in SDK Manager I see some APIs are partially installed.

How can I make them installed?

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. In the bottom right, click on "Show Package details"
2. Select the packages that you require
3. Install the missing modules